# Pure virtual destructor in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, destructor, pure-virtual

Is it wrong to write:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = 0;
};
```

for an abstract base class?

At least that compiles in MSVC... Will it crash at run time?

Comment: It may compile, but does it link?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Yes. You also need to implement the destructor:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = 0;
};

inline A::~A() { }
```

should suffice.

If you derive anything from A and then try to delete or destroy it, `A`'s destructor will eventually be called. Since it is pure and doesn't have an implementation, undefined behavior will ensue. On one popular platform, that will invoke the purecall handler and crash.

Edit: fixing the declaration to be more conformant, compiled with http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/

Comment: So it should be declared virtual ~A() { }, without the "= 0". It's not pure virtual if you provide an implementation

Comment: Um, yes it is. Pure only means a derived class also needs to provide an implementation.

Comment: Implementing pure virtual functions is in fact legal. Very useful for providing a default implementation but forcing subclasses to call it explicitly.

Comment: MSN and note if you have that definition in the header, you need to put "inline" before it to avoid violating the ODR (one definition rule)

Comment: Why does A::~A() have to be explicitly defined, since, I thought there is a default destructor for every object?  As in any type of inheritance, the chain of destructors is always called and the base class destructor doesn't have to always be defined.

Comment: The base class destructor always has to be defined if it will be invoked. If you never delete or explicitly destroy sublcasses of A, this doesn't matter. If you do, it does.

Comment: A better way to put it is that once you declare a destructor, it is not automatically implemented for you.

Comment: If you don't provide a definition for `A::~A()`, you should get a compile-time error—a link error.

Comment: @MSN , what do you mean by this undefined behavior and crash?
https://pastebin.com/Uz2Ny4z0
This program does not crash on Windows.  Is that the popular platform? The output is:
https://pastebin.com/PJNdktPY

Comment: @bobbogo "If you don't provide a definition for A::~A(), you should get a compile-time" -- not possible to see for the compiler. Only linker will detect it.

Comment: Would I, according to [this cpp core guideline](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c21-if-you-define-or-delete-any-default-operation-define-or-delete-them-all) need to `=default` the other special member methods as well?

Comment: Just a node: even though you "force" the derived class to declare the destructor by making it pure, it will be OK to have a derived class without any (user defined) destructor. https://godbolt.org/z/x7Tcko

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2001942/5825294), I did not know that you could write `virtual ~A() = 0 {};`.

Answer (score 49):

Private destructors: they will give you an error when you create an object of a derived class -- not otherwise. A diagnostic may appear though.

> **12.4 Destructors**
>
> 6 A destructor can be declared virtual (10.3) or pure virtual (10.4); if any objects of that class or any derived class are created in the program, the destructor shall be defined.

A class with a pure virtual destructor is an abstract class.
Note well:

> **10.4 Abstract classes**
>
> 2 A pure virtual function need be defined only if called with, or as if with (12.4), the qualified-id syntax (5.1).
>
> [*Note*:a function declaration cannot provide both a pure-specifier and a definition —end
>   note ]

Taken straight from the draft:

```
struct C {
   virtual void f() = 0 { }; // ill-formed
};
```

Comment: +1.  I think Herb Sutter also has some good info on this: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/031.htm.  It's interesting to note that any pure virtual function may have an implementation provided, not just destructors.

Comment: Yes, it's something you do in an interview to freak your interviewers ;)

Comment: It's actually not all that uncommon, in my experience.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Which one?

Comment: @Dirk - the "any function" scenario. It's not uncommon to find it used to implement some common behaviour.

Comment: @Neil: Ah, I see. I do use that often enough. Very handy.

Comment: Which version of C++ is required for that syntax? I tested it on g++ C++11 and didn't compile

Comment: wait wait, is it safe to use `= 0 { };` if the compiler accepts it?

Comment: @IvanSanz-Carasa, even citation of 10.4.2 above clearly states that it's not.