# error LNK2019 - Virtual destructor in abstract class

Tags: c++, lnk2019, virtual-destructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pure virtual destructor in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c)

I have two classes: the abstract "Game" class and the derived "TestGame" class.  All of the functions in TestGame are implemented separately to nothing (for the sake of getting it to compile).  I am only getting one error:

> TestGame.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol "public:
>   virtual __thiscall Game::~Game(void)"
>   (??1Game@@UAE@XZ) referenced in
>   function "public: virtual __thiscall
>   TestGame::~TestGame(void)"
>   (??1TestGame@@UAE@XZ)

Here are my class definitions:

```
class Game
{
public:
    virtual ~Game(void) = 0;

    virtual bool Initialize() = 0;
    virtual bool LoadContent() = 0;
    virtual void Update() = 0;
    virtual void Draw() = 0;
};

class TestGame: public Game
{
public:
    TestGame(void);
    virtual ~TestGame(void);

    virtual bool Initialize();
    virtual bool LoadContent();
    virtual void Update();
    virtual void Draw();
};
```

I've tried a couple of things but I feel that maybe I am missing something fundamental about how abstracting and deriving classes works.

Comment: Note the `virtual` keywords in the derived class are optionnal regarding to the standard. Maybe are they mnemotechnic, thats OK.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You actually need to define the destructor for the base class even though it is pure virtual, since it will be called when the derived class is destroyed.

```
virtual ~Game() { /* Empty implementation */ }
```

The `= 0` for pure virtual is not necessary, since you have other pure virtual functions to make your class abstract.

Comment: I assume you meant "destructor".

Comment: You don't need the =0 if you also provide the empty implementation (though it is not illegal, just slightly confusing to most).

Comment: @Martin York: you need the =0 if it's the only pure virtual method, to ensure the class is abstract, to prevent instantiation.

Comment: First, drop that "void", C++ doesn't need it. Second, you can't have pure virtual declaration (=0) and definition at the same place. You must provide definition outside of class (inline or not - your choice):
Game::~Game() {}

Comment: Thanks guys.  I ~Game(){} in the implementation and it works fine.

Comment: @ptpaterson: Do keep it `virtual`, though! It just doesn't need the `=0`.

Comment: @Gene: You're right. I thought `= 0` worked there but it doesn't. I think `inline` needs to be on the definition if it's in a header file to avoid problems with the ODR.