# Interface as in java in c++?

Tags: java, c++, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you declare an interface in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318064/how-do-you-declare-an-interface-in-c)

Somebody asked me a qustion: "In C++ there are no interfaces like in java. But event then you could realize them in c++, how would you do that?"

How? I would make a class with virtual methods. That would be look like an interface as in java or?

Thank you

Comment: Java uses interfaces as a poor man's substitute for multiple inheritance (which is forbidden in Java). C++ fully supports multiple inheritance. It doesn't need Java-style interfaces.

Comment: @close-voters: the alleged duplicate is not. no answer has been given yet of how to do Java-like interface implementation inheritance in C++. which isn't difficult at all, but which is the basic element of any answer to *this* question (and not so for the alleged duplicate).

Answer (score 10):

You can create interfaces in C++ using multiple inheritance.

You create a base class which is pure virtual (all functions =0) and then your classes inherit from this.

Multiple inheritance means you can inherit from as many of these as you like.

```
// Interface definition
class ISomethingable
{
public:
    virtual ~ISomethingable() {}
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;    
}

// Your code
class MyClass : public ISomethingable
{
public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
         // Do something concrete.
    }
}
```

See also: [How do you declare an interface in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/318064/15667)

Comment: There, you can vote to close as a duplicate now.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, just make a class with no member variables and pure virtual functions.

Answer (score 1):

An interface in C++ would be an [abstract base class](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr142.htm) -- one that can't be instantiated from. Unlike java interfaces, they can actually have partial implementation and member variables.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can do abstract classes in Java too. :-)

Comment: So that what i said. A class with virtual methods = abstract class or?

Comment: An analog to a java interface would be a C++ class where all it's methods are pure virtual. It would have no implementation, but would dictate a set of functions that must be implemented by some derived class.

Comment: @JeffPaquette "_where all it's methods are pure virtual._" except the destructor, it doesn't need to be pure and certainly must be implemented.</nitpick>

Comment: @curiousguy if the destructor isn't pure virtual, it's not an exactly interface because it provides implementation /nitpick-pick

Comment: @JeffPaquette but even a pure virtual destructor must be implemented!</extreme-nitpick>

Comment: @curiousguy Ah yes, you're correct.See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c