# How to use interfaces in c++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++, I have trouble understanding how interfaces work. I've set up a small example which doesn't work, and I don't understand what I've done wrong.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/318137/3149379) answer, which helped me declaring the interface, but (even if I still don't understand fully the declaration) my concern right now is more about the usage. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513537/3149379) answer too, but still, I can't use my interface, see this example :

shape.h

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual ~Shape(){}
    virtual int getArea() = 0;
};

#endif // SHAPE_H
```

rectangle.h

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H

#include "shape.h"

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    Rectangle(){}
    Rectangle(int w, int h) : width{w}, height{h} {}
    virtual int getArea();
private:
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
};

#endif // RECTANGLE_H
```

rectangle.cpp

```
#include "rectangle.h"

int Rectangle::getArea()
{
    return width * height;
}
```

weird.h

```
#ifndef WEIRD_H
#define WEIRD_H

#include "shape.h"

class Weird : public Shape
{
public:
    Weird(){}
    Weird(int a) : area(a){}
    virtual int getArea();
private:
    int area = 0;
};

#endif // WEIRD_H
```

weird.cpp

```
#include "weird.h"

int Weird::getArea()
{
    return area;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

#include "shape.h"
#include "weird.h"
#include "rectangle.h"

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<Shape> shapes;
    Shape shapeA = Weird(12);
    Shape shapeB = Rectangle(2, 3);

    shapes.push_back(shapeA);
    shapes.push_back(shapeB);

    int total = 0;
    for(auto&& s : shapes)
    {
       total += s.getArea();
    }

   printf("%d\n", total); //Would expect 18
}
```

When I build this, I get :

```
main.cpp:11:9: error: variable type 'Shape' is an abstract class
            Shape shapeA = Weird(12);
                  ^
./shape.h:8:18: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'getArea' in 'Shape'
        virtual int getArea() = 0;
                    ^
main.cpp:12:9: error: variable type 'Shape' is an abstract class
            Shape shapeB = Rectangle(2, 3);
                  ^
```

The second error bothers me, because not implementing `getArea()` in the `Shape` class is precisely what I'm expecting from an interface. The first and third errors, I don't understand at all. I tried to change the main to :

```
Weird shapeA = Weird(12);
Rectangle shapeB = Rectangle(2, 3);
```

But got errors from the vector complaining about `allocating an object of abstract class type 'Shape'`

I'm probably missing a few important things here, but I'm a bit stuck...

*EDIT : As suggested in comments, I used member initialization lists in constructors instead of assigning values to members in the body.*

Comment: Lookup the requirements for elements of `std::vector`, you'll be probably fine using a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>` instead.

Comment: Not the main point, but for the constructors you should use [member initialization lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) like `Rectangle::Rectangle(int w, int h) : width{w}, height{h}
{}`, not assigning the members inside the body like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++ inheritance only works when you have pointers or references to an object. You cannot have a `vector<Shape>` because `Shape` can't exist. I'm guessing you come from a background where object variables are always references (like Java).

So this is valid

```
std::vector<Shape*> shapes;
shapes.push_back(new Rectangle(2, 3));
```

but raw pointers are not good C++. So some sort of smart pointer is preferable

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> shapes;
shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Rectangle>(2, 3));
```

or

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> shapes;
shapes.push_back(std::make_unique<Rectangle>(2, 3));
```

Comment: It's not like inheritance doesn't work, it's _runtime polymorphism_ that is useful only when accessing objects through pointers/references to the base class, as _value semantics_ doesn't allow to copy derived objects into base instances.