# C++ "Virtual functions but no virtual destructors"

Tags: c++

I have a base class `Media` and several derived classes, namely `DVD`, `Book`, etc...
The base class is written as:

```
class Media{
    private:
        int id;
        string title;
        int year;
    public:
        Media(){ id = year = 0; title = ""; }
        Media(int _id, string _title, int _year): id(_id), title(_title), year(_year) {}
//      virtual ~Media() = 0;
        void changeID(int newID){ id = newID; }
        virtual void print(ostream &out);
};
```

The thing is: without the destructor, GCC gives me a bunch of warnings `class has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor`, but still compiles and my program works fine. Now I want to get rid of those annoying warnings so I satisfy the compiler by adding a virtual destructor, the result is: it doesn't compile, with the error:

```
undefined reference to `Media::~Media()`
```

Making the destructor pure virtual doesn't solve the problem.
So what has gone wrong?

Comment: Why do you want a pure virtual constructor in the first place? A empty virtual constructor works just well (and it amounts to the same number of non whitespace chars)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore That wasn't what I meant. I rephrase it for you: Why do you want the class Media to be abstract?

Comment: @drhirsch Usually because you want to disallow its creation. Perhaps an object of type Media doesn't make sense.

Comment: If someone just needs to disable the "class has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor" warnings, it's `-Wno-non-virtual-dtor`.  I'm not suggesting it as an answer to this question though.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to also define the virtual destructor, not only add it.

```
//Media.h
class Media{
    //....
    virtual ~Media() = 0;
};

//Media.cpp
#include "Media.h"
//....
Media::~Media() {};
```

The reason you get the warnings is that all classes that will be derived from should have a virtual or protected (credit @Steve) destructor, otherwise deleting an instance via a pointer to a base class results in undefined behavior.

**Note** you HAVE TO provide a definition for destructors, even if they are pure virtual.

Comment: "all classes that will be derived from should have a virtual destructor" - or a protected destructor, which will prevent outsiders from deleting via the wrong pointer. This is for cases where the outsider isn't supposed to directly delete anyway (for example because the objects are created via some factory that returns a smart pointer).

Comment: Can't believe I have to implement an empty destructor.
Problem solved, thanks guys!

Comment: @crazyfffan: If your compiler is new enough, you can also say `= default` (C++11 feature)

Comment: Isn't it enough just to define empty constructor: `virtual ~Media() {}` (Jerry Coffin's answer)?

Comment: @pevik If one can use `= default`, one should; user-providing a special member function, even if in practice the implementation is exactly what the default would do, can block or hinder other features.

Answer (score 33):

> The thing is: without the destructor, GCC gives me a bunch of warnings "class has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor", but still compiles and **my program works fine**

This is an annoying warning in Modern C++, but in old object-style C++ it is generally correct.

The problem is about the way your objects are destructed. A simple test:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {};
class Derived: public Base { public: ~Derived() { std::cout << "Aargh\n"; } };

int main() {
  Base* b = new Derived();
  Derived* d = new Derived();

  delete d;
  delete b;
}
```

This prints:

```
Aargh
```

Yep, only once.

The problem is that when you call `delete` on a variable of type `Base*`, the `Base::~Base()` method is called. If it is `virtual`, then the call is dynamically dispatched to the final method (based on the dynamic type), in this case `Derived::~Derived()`, but if it is not, then `Derived::~Derived()` is never called, thus never executed.

Therefore, if you wish to call `delete` (or use smart pointers which do it for you) on base types, then you need to add `virtual ~Base() {}` in their class definitions. This is why gcc warns you when you create a polymorphic class without a `virtual` destructor.

---

*Note: time changed, and since then I implemented `-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor` in Clang and it was replicated in gcc as well.*

*`-Wnon-virtual-dtor` is useful for library writers (as it warns on the base class), but may have a higher false positive rate; on the other hand [`-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor`](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#delete-non-virtual-dtor) fires at the call site, and has a much lower false positive rates (which you can generally work around by peppering `final` to remove the "polymorphic" property of the class).*

Comment: But note that least officially, most of this is speculation. Officially, destroying a derived object via a pointer/reference to base requires a virtual dtor--otherwise, the behavior is simply undefined.

Comment: There are other reasons you should give every class with at least one virtual function a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Spencer: can you name them? I can't think of anything, other than actually destructing the object correctly.

Answer (score 13):

What you have commented out is a pure-virtual declaration for a destructor. That means the function must be overridden in a derived class to be able to instantiate an object of that class.

What you want is just a definition of the destructor as a virtual function:

```cpp
virtual ~Media() {}
```

In C++ 11 or newer, it's generally preferable to define this as defaulted instead of using an empty body:

```cpp
virtual ~Media() = default;
```

Answer (score 7):

You should implement the virtual destructor, not make it pure virtual.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c) similar question (identical maybe from the point of view of the virtual destructor error, not the warning) for more info.

EDIT: more generic solution, in reply to LuchianGrigore's comment (thank you for pointing it out)

You can also make the destructor pure virtual and implement as it is pointed in the above mentioned question.

The use of virtual destructors in you classes should be to prevent instantiation of the base class (i.e. when you have no other pure virtual methods to make the class abstract).

Comment: Pure virtual destructors have their purpose. But even if declared pure, a definition is still required.

Comment: Yes, my answer was only regarding the error. I'll add the use of pure virtual destructors in a class and a way of implementing them in my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment declaration first and then
Try adding following line after class declaration

```
Media::~Media(){}
```

Comment: No. Adding this AFTER the class declaration will yield multiple definition during linkage. The definition must be in only one translation unit.

Comment: That's still not correct. Adding it after the class declaration, inside a header file, will result in error.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore can you tell me what kind of error will the compiler give if I add definition in .h file? It works just fine on Visual Studio

Comment: @Hiren If you put it in a header file included in multiple c++ sources, you'll get a linker error because the definition would be replicated once per .cpp file.