# C++ Program Error - Virtual destructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor, pure-virtual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pure virtual destructor in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c)

```
class A{
    public:
        virtual ~A()=0;
};

class B:public A{
        int *i;
    public:
        ~B() {delete i;}
};

int main(){
    B* temp = new B;
}
```

I'm just trying to have B be an implementation of A. For some reason I cannot do this.

Comment: what is the relationship between B and S?

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to change that.

Comment: Note that right now, your `B::~B` has undefined behavior -- it deletes `i`, but `i` was never initialized.

Comment: You aren't dynamically allocating `i` anywhere, so the `delete i;` will crash.

Comment: What do you mean "For some reason I cannot do this"? What happens when you try? What do you expect to happen instead? Where is the code where you attempt to use `B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ destructor can be pure virtual:

```
class A{
    public:
        virtual ~A()=0;
};
```

But in every case it needs to be implemented:

```
inline A::~A() {}
```

Otherwise A is not usable class. I mean destruction of derived (S/B) is not possible. And possibility of  destruction is needed in this line:

```
  B* temp = new B;
```

because in case of throwed exception - compiler will automatically destructs temp...

Comment: Provide inline empty implementation of your virtual destructor in header file. There is no other way. Otherwise destruction of derived (S/B) is not possible.

Comment: thanks adding that line fixed my program.

Comment: I don't think the line with `B` actually can invoke any destructor, since if `new` throws it does so before completing the construction of `B` (actually before even starting it; it fails to get the raw memory), so the destructor `B::~B` will not be called. But this (a line calling for the _construction_ of a `B`) is as good a place as can be found for the compiler to warn you about the impossibility to destruct a `B`; either you will do that ultimately, or you've got a memory leak.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen An exception can be thrown from inside of `B::B()` after constructing its `A` part. So compiler needs to have access to implementation of `A::~A()`... I mean `B::~B() : A(), i(new int(13)) {}` In case of `bad_alloc` for `new int(13)` - `A::~A()` will be invoked...

Comment: @PiotrNycz: You are right, I overlooked that possibility. (And you meant `B::B()` where you wrote `B::~B()`; I'm sure you would never dream of calling `new` from a destructor.)

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment `"Yeah i want A to basically be just a container class. Do not want any implementation of A"`. 
Your class B shall `protected/private` inherited from A instead of `public` inherite.
`virtual ~A()` is allowed to be `pure` but you still need to provide implementation to `~A()`.

```
class A{
public:
  virtual ~A() = 0
  {
    cout << "~A"<<endl;
  }
};

class B : private /*protected*/ A{
  int *i;
public:
  B() : A(){
    i = new int;
  }
  ~B() {
    delete i;
  }
};

int main(){
    B* temp = new B;
    delete temp;
    return 0;
}
```