# How do I implement a pure virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, instantiation, pure-virtual

Here's the format of the code:

```
class C
{
public:
    C();
    virtual ~C() = 0;
};

class D : public C
{
public:
    D();
    ~D();
};

C::C(){
}

C::~C(){
}

D::D(){
}

D::~D(){
}

int main(){
    C *c = new C();
    D *d = new D();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to instantiate `c` I get the following error:

```
1>c:\main.cpp(59): error C2259: 'C' : cannot instantiate abstract class
```

I know I cannot call the virtual destructor, but there is something terribly I don't know on the concepts. Can someone explain me?

Comment: You can't instantiate a class that has a pure virtual method.

Comment: If you want to instantiate `C`, you shouldn't have any pure functions. Are you sure you need your destructor to be pure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c?rq=1

Comment: @chris, I know about it. What if I have the pure virtual destructor? How can the above problem be solved?

Comment: @Ashwinkumar: The problem is that you both (1) have a pure virtual destructor in your class and (2) are trying to instantiate the class. It can be solved by either (1) *not* having a pure virtual destructor in your class or (2) *not* trying to instantiate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't instantiate `C` because you have explicitly said it's destructor is undefined.

You could just do:

```
class C
{
public:
    C();
    virtual ~C() {}
};
```

instead.

You can leave `C` exactly "as is" as long as you don't try to instantiate it (i.e. you only create `D`s, but you can pass them around as `C`s.

Answer (score 4):

“=0” means you define this method as pure virtual. If a class contains any pure virutal method, then the class is pure virtual. You can not instantiate pure virtual class, because there is no implementation for pure virtual method.

Comment: This explains my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

class C is called `abstract class` in C++ which can't be initialized.

> §10.4/2 Abstract classes An abstract class is a class that can be used
>   only as a base class of some other class; no objects of an abstract
>   class can be created except as subobjects of a class derived from it.
>   A class is abstract if it has at least one pure virtual function.

change `C *c = new C();` to `C *c = new D();` should work.

Or you can make class C non-abstract class by removing `=0`

```
class C{
public:
  C() {}
  virtual ~C() {}
};

C* c = new C();  // this is ok
```

Comment: +1. Added paragraph number to reduce ambiguity in standard reference location.