# virtual destructor vs pure virtual destructor

Tags: c++, interface, destructor

Are some difference between virtual destructor and pure virtual destructor? In my design I always used pure virtual destructor:

```
class MyInterface {
public:
    virtual ~MyInterface() = 0;
    virtual void doA() const = 0;
    virtual void doB( int ) = 0;
};
inline MyInterface::~MyInterface {}
```

Well I know why the dctor must be virtual but I don't understand the difference with this:

```
class MyInterface {
public:
    virtual ~MyInterface() {}
    virtual void doA() const = 0;
    virtual void doB( int ) = 0;
};
```

Comment: Pure virtual means the class can not be instantiated.  Any derived class must override the pure virtuals with non-pures or the derived class can not be instantiated also.

Comment: Is the first one really a pure virtual destructor, since you are providing an inline implementation?

Comment: I've to implement it, this is an exception to the rule to allow the call of base dctor from derived

Comment: @brianbeuning: AFAIK, there is no way to override a pure virtual destructor. So it leads me to question its existence. We need a virtual destructor, for sure, but "pure virtual destructor" seems like an oxymoron.

Comment: I've read the post that Andy has suggested... for what I've understand is just to force derived class to clean-up, nothing more

Comment: [Pure virtual destructor in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c) is more relevant. The difference is that the first one should require the derived class to implement a destructor (but I can't find a compiler that enforces that, so they are equivalent).

Comment: A pure virtual destructor can also be used to make a class abstract, even without any other pure virtual methods.

Comment: the difference is that first snippet require that derived class implements dctor, 2nd snipped instead doesn't

Comment: @user315052 You cannot find a compiler that "enforces" that because the rules say that if you don't provide a destructor the compiler creates one for you. So the derived class **always** implements the destructor, and therefore all is well.