# Why does declaring runtime polymorphism for template instantiations result in linker error?

Tags: c++, templates, linker, virtual-inheritance

I have a perfectly working code:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
class ThreadImplementation {
    ...
    void launch(){...}
    ~ThreadImplementation(){...}
};
...
ThreadImplementation<Ts...> *t = new ThreadImplementation<Ts...>(debugName,func,args...);
...
// std::vector< std::unique_ptr< ThreadImplementation<> > >  thread_107_allThreads;
thread_107_allThreads.emplace_back(t);
...
```

where thread_107_allThreads as of now stores only the ones with no template parameters, hence ThreadImplementation<> in the declaration

now if I add above all

```
class AnyThreadImplementation {
    public:
    virtual void launch() = 0;
    virtual ~AnyThreadImplementation() = 0;
};
```

and make ONLY the following 3 changes (no casting, no change in use, nor in test):

```
class ThreadImplementation : public AnyThreadImplementation {

    virtual void launch(){...}

    virtual ~ThreadImplementation(){...}
```

(although the last 2 changes does not affect the result ie: I get the same error if I miss the virtual's in front of the actual implementations in the subclass)

and I get:

```
/tmp/test-fuPonc.o: In function `_ZN20ThreadImplementationIJEEC2EPKcPFvvE':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN20ThreadImplementationIJEEC2EPKcPFvvE[_ZN20ThreadImplementationIJEEC2EPKcPFvvE]+0xbb): undefined reference to `AnyThreadImplementation::~AnyThreadImplementation()'
/tmp/test-fuPonc.o: In function `_ZN20ThreadImplementationIJEED2Ev':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN20ThreadImplementationIJEED2Ev[_ZN20ThreadImplementationIJEED2Ev]+0x233): undefined reference to `AnyThreadImplementation::~AnyThreadImplementation()'
test.cpp:(.text._ZN20ThreadImplementationIJEED2Ev[_ZN20ThreadImplementationIJEED2Ev]+0x267): undefined reference to `AnyThreadImplementation::~AnyThreadImplementation()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure virtual destructor should be defined too.

Relevant quote from N3376 12.4/9

> A destructor can be declared virtual or pure virtual; **if any objects of that class or any
> derived class are created in the program, the destructor shall be defined.**

```
class AnyThreadImplementation {
    public:
    virtual void launch() = 0;
    virtual ~AnyThreadImplementation() = 0;
};

AnyThreadImplementation::~AnyThreadImplementation() {}
```

Comment: @user1358 since standard qualify that. Since destructor of base class should be called, if it's virtual, but you cannot call pure virtual function.