# Linker complains about lack of implementation for pure virtual destructor for base abstract class

Tags: c++11, linker, abstract-class, pure-virtual, virtual-destructor

Something that I learned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c) question, but that I thought I'd give a more detailed and easily searchable answer to, is that if you have a base abstract class meant to be inherited such as this, and you've made its destructor virtual pure by adding "= 0" to its end:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};
```

and you try to derive a class with it, like this:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    ~Derived();
};

Derived::~Derived() {
    // nothing, this is an example
}
```

you will get linker errors that are complaining about a lack of implementation for the base's destructor, despite it being a pure virtual method (on MSVC you might get LNK2019 and LNK 2001 errors). So how do you solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure virtual destructor in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you need to provide an implementation of the base's destructor, despite it being a pure virtual function. The reasoning can be found in [the question I linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c).

Knowing this, we can make changes to the base class, and this will work!

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};

// This was added to get rid of the error
Base::~Base() {
    // nothing, although you can add your own code if necessary
}

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    ~Derived();
};

Derived::~Derived() {
    // nothing, this is an example
}
```