# virtual destrutors vs normal methods in C++

Tags: c++, destructor, virtual-functions, virtual-destructor

Consider the following three programs in C++:

#### program 1

```
struct base{
  virtual ~base() =0;
};

struct derived: public base{
  ~derived();
};

derived::~derived(){}

int main(){}
```

#### program 2

```
struct base{
  virtual ~base() =0;
};

struct derived: public base{
  ~derived(){}
};

int main(){}
```

#### program 3

```
struct base{
  virtual void func() =0;
};

struct derived: public base{
  void func();
};

void derived::func(){}

int main(){}
```

The programs #2 and #3 compile and run fine however the first gives the following error:

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "base::~base()", referenced from:
>     derived::~derived() in main-d923b9.o
> ls: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

I'd like to know why I am unable to define virtual destructors outside of the class definition however I am able to do it inside the class definition. Additionally I can define methods outside the class, just not destructors.

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript to me ? The C++ tag would be better suited to this question

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to change it from the previous question I asked. Also thanks for the catch on the constructor vs destructor. the question is still valid however

Comment: None of these code samples actually compile (or provide the linker error you posted). Please provide real [mcve]s, don't invent code on the fly

Comment: `virtual ~base() =0;`  pure virtual     `virtual ~base() {}`  virtual     `virtual ~base() =0 {};`  pure virtual with impl

Comment: A pure virtual destructor must be defined and it can be done only outside of the class definition due to syntax issues.

Comment: all the code should either compile/run now or give the error. If it doesn't let me know and I'll look into it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure virtual destructor in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong

```
struct base{
  virtual ~base() =0;
};
```

because `base::~base` is not defined. Even though it has been declared as a pure virtual, it needs to be defined (outside of the class, there is no syntaxic way to declare a function as pure virtual and define it inline) so `derived` can inherit from it:

```
struct base
{
    virtual ~base() = 0;
};

base::~base() {}
```

---

> I'd like to know why I am unable to define virtual destructors outside of the class definition

Well, you can: I just did.

---

Then, why do you need to implement a function (`~base`) which has been declared pure virtual?

Since `derived` inherit from `base`, when an object of type `derived` is destructed, it necessarily calls `base`'s destructor. This is how inheritance work. In a sense, `derived::~derived` needs to link with `base::~base`. Even though `base::~base` is a pure virtual (meaning a class inheriting from `base` is not a complete type unless it defines a destructor) it *needs* to be defined so `~derived` finds it and the linker become happy.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with pure virtual destructor declaration. Your wording is wrong.

Comment: ok, I added base::~base(){} to the code and it works. I'm confused though because I thought that you didn't need to implement virtual functions and it seems like your implementing it when you do this

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin care to expand on that? I don't get it.

Comment: to phrase my question differently, why is base::~base(){} not needed in the second 2 programs

Comment: then why does it compile and run fine in the second 2 cases?

Comment: It's needed in all the programs. Sounds like a compiler bug if program 2 built without error.

Comment: are you sure that its a bug? I just ran program 2 on mac and on linux, neither gave an error

Comment: @fred added explanation

Comment: @fred: the difference between a regular method and a destructor is that at the end of a derived class destructor it's as if there's an implicit call to the base class destructor, so if that isn't defined you'll get a linker error.

Comment: ok that makes sense. Thanks a lot for all the help, I'm still concerned however that the second program is running and compiling on both my mac and linux machines

Comment: @fred it doesn't really come in as a surprise, the compiler just sees a class declaration that nobody uses, that translation unit doesn't produce anything that references any of those destructors. The first example instead emits the destructor for `derived`, which implicitly references the destructor of `base`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to why program 2 builds lays in how link works. When function definition is outside the class declaration, linker needs to create a body of the function in the final binary file so it needs to have ~base() definition as well.

If you put in case 2 `derived d;` in main body, you'll get the same error as in case 1 as the linker will have to create the derived member functions definitions and will need ~base() body as in case 1.