# Game Development - Items - Enums or Inhertance for type

Tags: c++, inheritance, enums, game-development

I'm currently working on a project for school where we have to design a text-based adventure game. 
In my game I've made an 'Item' class but was wondering what the best way to differentiate between items would be.
I was first thinking inheritance:

```
class Item{
protected:
    //generic item info (cost, name, etc.)
public:
    Item();
    ~Item();
};

class Weapon: public Item{
private: 
    //weapon specific info
public:
    //functions
};
```

OR have an enum definition of weapon types?

```
enum ItemType{
Weapon,
//more item types (armor, consumable, etc)
};

class Item{
private:
    ItemType _itemType;
//more code
};
```

Just wondering on which is the best implementation especially if I plan on expanding and adding to the game in the future! Also if one is prefered since the player will have an 'inventory' -> std::vector<*Item> _inventory;

Best!

Comment: [Before you start playing with pure virtual destructors, give this link a read.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c). You may find `virtual ~Item() = default;` more useful.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted - seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me, and the answer @user4581301 provided could be useful to a lot of new programmers.

Comment: @TimMcCabe Because this is an opinion-based question. Note how the answer starts with "I *like* both options".

Comment: @PasserBy and then I explain why I like both. In the Asker's case they work best stacked together. I'll give some credit to the Too Broad close reason though. There are dozens of ways to do this. This question has probably been asked and answered a few times. I've probably even answered it once or twice, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

I like both options, but in different cases.

Inheritance rocks for handling different behaviours for different item types but I group together items with relatively few differences, maybe with an `enum` to tell them apart.

For example, there are huge differences between the healing potion and the sword but there may be many different types of healing potions or swords that differ only in the amount of healing or damage done to the target. Dozens of different swords can be described with a `string` to name them and a range of damage they can do. A "Minor Healing Potion" perhaps restores 1 to 6 health, but a "Major Healing Potion" restores 10 to 60. That's the only difference. No need for different code, just different instances with different values in the member variables. Big Sword does more damage than Little Sword (same class, different instances), but Flaming Sword has a chance of igniting the target, so it gets its own class, possibly with multiple instances For Big Flaming Sword and Little Flaming Sword that do different damage and have different chances of turning the target into a living torch.

Inheritance is most useful when you build in sufficient virtual functions to avoid having to play silly games with `dynamic_cast`.

Consider for example

```
void use(entity & on) = 0;
```

as an `Item` virtual function. With it you can `use` an `Item` on any `entity` without knowing what it is. If you invoke `use` on a `sword`, `sword`'s implementation of `use` will attempt to remove health from `on`. Invoking `use` on `vorpal_sword` will attempt to decapitate `on` as well as doing damage.

Invoke `use` on a `healing_potion` and it will attempt to restore health to `on`.

Invoke `use` on a `flux_capacitor` and it will send `on` to another time. Have fun coding that.

The options are limited to your imagination and ability to code the special effects. And all of this would just take some very simple code in the main logic:

```
_inventory[index]->use(target);
```

The main logic doesn't know what the `Item` is. It doesn't even need to know what `target` is. It just knows it's `use`ing item 42 on `target`.

And now for a note on `_inventory`. You probably want

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> _inventory;
```

Where possible use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) to manage ownership of objects. You don't always want to simply point at a generic `Item` in another list. Take for example the Lamp of Three Wishes. Aladdin will need a private instance if only to keep track of the number of wishes he's got left.