# How to correctly write c++ makefile when dealing with base and derived classes

Tags: c++, derived-class, base-class

So I have a base class called RequestChannel and I have another class that is derived from it called FIFORequestChannel. I also have a file called `trial.cpp` where I have my main. I therefore have following files:

```
RequestChannel.h
FIFORequestChannel.h (includes RequestChannel.h)
FIFORequestChannel.cpp (includes FIFORequestChannel.h)
trial.cpp (includes FIFORequestChannel.h)
```

I didn't see the point of having .cpp file for RequestChannel since it is just my base class and no implementation is provided. I have made the following makefile to compile it:

```
all: trial

FIFORequestChannel.o: FIFORequestChannel.h RequestChannel.h FIFORequestChannel.cpp
    g++ -g -w -Wall -O1 -std=c++11 -c FIFORequestChannel.cpp 

trial: trial.cpp FIFORequestChannel.o  
    g++ -g -w -Wall -O1 -std=c++11 -o trial trial.cpp FIFORequestChannel.o -lpthread

clean:
    rm -rf *.o  trial
```

My problem is that I am trying to create a makefile for it but I keep getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for RequestChannel", referenced from:
      typeinfo for FIFORequestChannel in FIFORequestChannel.o
  "vtable for RequestChannel", referenced from:
      RequestChannel::RequestChannel() in FIFORequestChannel.o
      RequestChannel::~RequestChannel() in FIFORequestChannel.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [trial] Error 1
```

I don't know if I am also supposed to include `RequestChannel.h` in `FIFOFIFORequestChannel.cpp` even though it is already included in `FIFOFIFORequestChannel.h` already
Here is the code:

RequestChannel.h

```
class RequestChannel {
public:
 RequestChannel(){};
 ~RequestChannel(){};
 virtual int cwrite (string)= 0;
 virtual string cread ();
};
```

FIFORequestChannel.h

```
#include "RequestChannel.h"
using namespace std;

class FIFORequestChannel: public RequestChannel {
private:

public:
   FIFORequestChannel();
  ~FIFORequestChannel();
   int cwrite (string);
   string cread();
};
```

FIFORequestChannel.cpp

```
#include "FIFORequestChannel.h"

using namespace std;

FIFORequestChannel::FIFORequestChannel(){
    cout << "Constructor worked" <<endl;
}

FIFORequestChannel::~FIFORequestChannel(){
    cout << "Destructor worked" <<endl;
}

int FIFORequestChannel::cwrite (string){
    cout << "cwrite() inside of derived class" << endl;
}
string FIFORequestChannel::cread(){
    cout << "cread() inside of derived class" << endl;
}
```

trial.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "FIFORequestChannel.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    RequestChannel* rq = new FIFORequestChannel();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `make`. You'd get the same error running the build commands manually.

Comment: "*... no implementation is provided*" is probably the source of your problems, but it's hard to say without a [mcve].

Comment: Yep, `RequestChannel();` is declared but not implemented anywhere. Exactly what the linker is complaining about.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with `make`.

The issue is that

```
class RequestChannel {
public:
    RequestChannel();
    ~RequestChannel();
};
```

declares two functions (the constructor and destructor of `RequestChannel`), but they're not implemented anywhere.

The easiest solution in your case might be to simply leave the class empty:

```
class RequestChannel {};
```

Comment: So what would I have to do if I had to override some functions

Comment: @PapeSowTraore You mean custom code in the constructor/destructor? You'd have to define those functions somewhere, either inline (`class RequestChannel { public: RequestChannel() { ... } ~RequestChannel() { ... } };`) or in a corresponding .cpp file.

Comment: And would I need to make the RequestChannel constructor and destructor virtual as well if I want to overwrite  them in the derived class of FIFORequestChannel

Comment: @Pape Sow Traore yes , but given the simplicity of the class (just constructor and destructor) there isn't a need for it at all as every class has a constructor and destructor provided by the compiler if a default constructor and destructor are not written. Is there a specific design pattern you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @PapeSowTraore Constructors can't be virtual. Destructors need to be virtual if you want to be able to `delete` objects through a base pointer (e.g. `delete rq` where `rq` was declared as `RequestChannel *`).

Comment: I have updated what I have and the error I am getting. Hopefully this helps you see what I am trying to do as a whole. I have implemented both the destructor and constructor in the base class

Answer (score 1):

1. This is not a problem of `make`
2. The linker complains about missing implementation of RequestChannel() and ~RequestChannel()
3. There is more to know about derivation from a base class:

   - **Prevention of memory leak**: see [question about virtual destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors): if you call `delete` on a base class pointer (`RequestChannel*`), which points to an object of type `FIFORequestChannel`, then the destructor of `RequestChannel` is called instead of the one of `FIFORequestChannel`. This is usually not that what is expected nor what is needed. That's a very common reason for a memory leak, especially for C++ Newcomer. Declare your base class and subclass destructors `virtual` to avoid that.
   - **Prevention of instantiation of abstract class (*interface*) by making the destructor pure virtual**: `RequestChannel` seems to be an abstract base class, which is not supposed to be instantiated. The instantiation is disallowed by declaring a pure virtual destructor `virtual ~RequestChannel()=0;`. Anyway, you need to provide an implementation of the pure virtual destructor according to the [question about pure virtual destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c). Usually, pure virtual functions are not defined in the same class.
4. Move definition of destructor into RequestChannel.cpp, because otherwise you *may* get multiple definitions, if you include RequestChannel.h elsewhere. Alternatively it can be defined as `inline`, but I never tried it, if it works as intended.

That's why I would recommend to do it like this:

```
//RequestChannel.h

class RequestChannel
{
public:
    virtual ~RequestChannel()=0; //virtual: to call derived destructor
                                 //=0: pure virtual, making the class abstract
};

//RequestChannel.cpp

RequestChannel::~RequestChannel() {}
```

Comment: Quick question, how can I make the following line: virtual string cread() is giving the following error "Illegal Instruction 4". Do I need to add "=0" even though that function returns a string?

Comment: I cannot say if this is the reason. You can try. Furthermore: please specify the name of the `string` argument of `cwrite`: `virtual cwrite (string s)=0;`. Also in the derived class and the cpp.