# C++ Make a class that cannot be instantiated

Tags: c++

I want to create two base class that cannot be instantiated.
I wrote the code as below, but it gave a compile error.

```
class Test {
std::string x_;
public:
    Test(std::string x): x_{x} {}
};

class BaseCompartment {
    Test x_;
protected:
    BaseCompartment(Test x): x_{x} {}
    virtual ~BaseCompartment() = 0;
    
    const Test& getTest1() const {
        return x_;
    }
}; 

class BaseTempCompartment: public BaseCompartment {
    Test y_;
protected:
    BaseTempCompartment(Test x, Test y): y_{y}, BaseCompartment(x) {}
    virtual ~BaseTempCompartment() = 0;
    
    const Test& getTest2() const {
        return y_;
    }  
}; 

class XTempCompartment: public BaseTempCompartment {
public:
    XTempCompartment(Test x, Test y): BaseTempCompartment(x, y) {}
    ~XTempCompartment() {}
};

int main() {
    XTempCompartment x {Test("1"), Test("2")};

    return 0;
}
```

I'm sure there are tons of errors in the code above.

`The BaseCompartment and BaseTempCompartment` classes contain a variable`(Test).`

I want to use these `Test classes` in the `XTempCompartment` class by calling `getTest1() and getTest2()`.

My goal is not to let `BaseCompartment and BaseTempCompartment` classes be instantiated.

Do I have to call it in abstract like below to create the `Test class`?

```
BaseCompartment(Test x): x_{x} {}
```

Also Is the correct usage for getting test variables like below?

```
const Test& getTest1() const {
    return x_;
}
```

How can I make the above code executable?

How can I write the above code better for these purposes?

Comment: Make all constructors protected and its destructor virtual

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c

Comment: Assuming you didn't forget to implement the destructors, [fix these warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/qe5dnPzK5) and it seems ok.

Comment: Pure virtual destructor is a problem: https://godbolt.org/z/1cfb3P69Y droping `= 0` fixes issue (it is possibloe to have it as pure virtual destructor, but it is unusual and should not be practiced).

Comment: A pure virtual destructor must still be defined, since destruction of any instance of a derived class implicitly calls base class destructors (whether they are pure virtual or not).   In general, a class cannot be instantiated if it either declares a pure virtual function or has a base with a pure virtual (non-destructor) function that it doesn't override.

Comment: @Peter ```A pure virtual destructor must still be defined```.  I didn't understand exactly why we had to write as pure virtual. Because doesn't it do the same job in virtual destructor(not pure)?

Comment: A pure virtual destructor can be used to ensure the class itself cannot be instantiated (even if, for example, it is a derived class that overrides all pure virtuals that it inherits, but it serves as a base for other [presumably instantiable] classes and we still don't want to instantiate it).

Comment: @Peter Adding ```BaseCompartment ::~BaseCompartment () {}``` and ```BaseTempCompartment::~BaseTempCompartment() {}``` after the class decleration makes code OK, right?

Answer (score 0):

U should make constructors protected, so u can access them only from instances of inherited classes.

And u make destructors virtual, so the it gets destroyed when u destroy instances of inherited classes.

Comment: Making constructors `protected` only prevents unrelated classes or functions from instantiating the class.   Derived classes, `friend`s, and member functions of the class itself can still instantiate classes that have protected constructors (unless the class has one or more pure virtual functions).